# XSLT: Displaying texts with an attribute only

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<text>
    <sentence type="grocery">I bought <fruit> apples</fruit> at the grocery store.</sentence>
    <sentence type="grocery">I also bought <fruit> bananas</fruit> at the store.</sentence>
    <sentence>Then, I bought a basket at another store.</sentence>
</text>
```

My current xslt looks like this (Big thanks to michael.hor257k):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/text">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="sentence"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sentence"> 
        <p> 
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p> 
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="fruit"> 
         <span style="color:red;"> 
             <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </span> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

BUT, I need the output as the following example (only for the specific attribute `<sentence type="grocery">`):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>I bought <span style="color:red;"> apples</span> at the grocery store.</p>
        <p>I also bought <span style="color:red;"> bananas</span> at the story.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help with the XSLT. Thanks.

Comment: Change `<xsl:apply-templates select="sentence"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="sentence[@type='grocery']"/>` and then [get a good XSLT/XPath book](http://a.co/b9bi5Wd) to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="sentence[@type='grocery']"/>
```

instead of

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="sentence"/>
```

It removes all sentences which doesn't have the "type" attribute with attribute value "grocery".